# Excluir arquivos com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Quero deletar um registro do BD que contém uma imagem. Quando efetuar tal ação, excluir também essa mesma imagem da pasta onde se encontra. Como proceder para fazer tal ação?

Comment: A tua pergunta fala sobre uma coisa, mas o teu código espelha outra. Especificamente o que pretendes fazer é apagar um ficheiro quando apagas um registo da BD ou apagar a directoria "receitas" ? Com o teu código que agora meteste na pergunta, estás a apagar a pasta e não um ficheiro dentro da mesma. Relativamente ao erro que obténs, é falta de permissões na pasta para apagar a mesma, provavelmente quem a criou não foi o utilizador que a está a tentar apagar.

Comment: Desculpa pelo meus erros. Editei a pergunta, acho que deu para esclarecer mais, senão, desculpa mais uma vez!

Answer (score 4):

O *helper* de ficheiros do [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) permite-te eliminar ficheiros num determinado caminho:

```php
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($caminho);
```

Se pretendes eliminar apenas um ficheiro, serás mais bem servido utilizando a função [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) do PHP:

```php
$caminhoParaFicheiro = '/caminho/para/ficheiro/bubu.jpg';

if (unlink($caminhoParaFicheiro)) {
     echo 'Bubu morreu';
}
else {
     echo 'Não foi possível matar o BuBu';
}
```

Como podes chamar a função unlink do PHP:

Comment: Entende sua lógica. Mas a exclusão da imagem é feita através de uma lista de registro, onde vou ter o botão para efetuar tal ação. Como eu poderia proceder?

Comment: +1 um pelo uso do Bubu ahahah

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar um arquivo só:

```
<?php

$file = '/dir/src/arquivo.png';

if(unlink($file)){

echo 'Excluido com sucesso';

}else{

echo 'Erro ao excluir';

}

?>
```

Para excluir vários arquivos:

```
<?php

$dir = '/dir/src/'; //Irá excluir todos do diretório src

$open = opendir($dir);

while($read = readdir($open)){

if($read != '.' && $read != '..'){

$e = @unlink($dir.$read);

if($e){
echo 'Arquivo {$read} excluido com sucesso <br>';
}else{
echo 'Erro ao excluir o arquivo {$read} <br>';
}

}

}

?>
```